# Chrome: No time or seek when playing WAV PCM file

Tags: google-chrome

I have an application that reads audio from some telephony equipment and allows users to listen in a browser.  Format of the audio file from soxi:

```
Onput File     : 'audio.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:02:42.15 = 1297200 samples ~ 12161.2 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 2.59M
Bit Rate       : 128k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Playing this on any browsers works fine except Chrome.  It plays the audio but the time is listed at "00:00" and the seek bar doesn't work.  It doesn't matter if I stream the audio from my application or save it locally and load it directly into Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the length of the file is not embedded in the "fmt " chunk. The way soxi calculated it was by analizing the whole file.

Comment: Is that fixable my modifying the header in the middle?  It does get passed a valid content-length.

Comment: Content length does not indicate the length in time

Comment: If you don't know, just say so.  "read the manual" isn't useful.

Comment: It gets complicated. The chunks are complex at some times